# Como importar modelo de outro moddulo no Odoo?

Tags: python-3.x

Num módulo do Odoo, existe uma seção em `__manifest__.py`, onde se indica quais são as dependências.

**__manifest__.py**

```
...

'depends': ['base', 'mrp'],
...
```

Com eu acesso os recursos de **mrp** a partir do meu módulo?